# Saved Search for items that are not in a bin location

Tags: mysql, sql, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

I am trying to put a NetSuite saved search together that shows only items that are not in a bin location. For this I am making an Item Search type...

I added Criteria:

`Formula (Numeric)` `CASE WHEN {inventorylocation} = {binonhand.location} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` *is* `1`

&

`Location On Hand` *is not* `0`

&

`Bin On Hand:On Hand` *is not* `0`

The `Formula (Numeric)` I used in my Results was:

`NVL({locationquantityonhand},0)-(SUM/* comment */(NVL({binonhand.quantityonhand},0)) OVER(PARTITION BY {name}))`

This formula does what I want it to do, but it still shows the 0 value lines, and you can't use the sum function like this in the criteria. Does anyone have any tips/suggestions that will allow me to filter out the 0 return lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NetSuites aggregation rather than analytic Sum.

Summary Criteria: Sum of Bin on Hand: On Hand > 0

Results: Minimum of Formula Numeric: Max({locationquantityonhand}) - Sum({binonhand.quantityonhand})

EDIT

To see location on hand not in bin on hand, replace the above summary Criteria with
[image: Example Summary Criteria]

Comment: I appreciate the reply! Using your suggestion I've gotten this close to what I was looking for, I had to modify it a bit, I put your formula in both the criteria summary and the results which worked. The issue I'm running into now is for items that don't have any material in {binonhand} but there is some in {locationquantityonhand}, the results don't display for these lines even when using NVL({binonhand.quantityonhand},0). Kinda weird, any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated!